# CoreAudio: Playing system sounds and record playing sound in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio

I have a problem with recording system sounds that my application plays. Similar to the 'Talking Tom' iOS application my app should record the screen video and sound. The screen recording and convert to video, is working fine, the problem is with recording audio using core Audio. I am using Core Audio for the 1st time, please help me in solving my problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[AudioRecordind using coreAudio](https://github.com/aranm/iPhone-ExtAudioFile-Record)

This Application is usefull in my project

Comment: It may be hard to notice, but the question *does* ask "How do I record audio currently played by my application" -- which is *exactly what the linked example code does*. Hence, I am **very** reluctantly up-voting. Honestly, after wasting over an hour studying the code, I wish it was fair to down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a few more details about the problem you are having. Core Audio covers allot of ground and it’s hard to give just general advice. That being said here is a tutorial that might help

http://www.chupamobile.com/tutorial/details/47

Comment: That uses AVFoundation and not Core Audio.